# Magento2 - add Product to cart with out-stock status

Tags: magento2, checkout, addtocart

Is it possible add product to cart with stock status = out-stock.

I used plugin to override method with afterIsSalable, with this add-cart-button showing but not adding product into cart.

Note: backorder setting already enabled.

Error message showing:
"There are no source items with the in stock status"
"This product is out of stock."Z

This is urgent.

Answer (score 1):

You cant add any product to cart if the quantity is zero without backorders being enabled.
you can go to `catalog->products->manage products->select the particular product ->advanced inventory->and set backorders to Allow quantity below 0`. Then clear cache using `php bin/magento c:f` and `php bin/magento c:c` after that run indexing using  `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and check it again, you will be able to addtocart it.